# Замена буквы по шаблону в регулярном выражении

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, pandas, dataframe

Есть прайс, в котором для каждой строки задана длина ширина высота в формате ДхШхВ. Есть желание букву нашего алфавита между числами, попавшими под шаблон заменить на [en] x (икс), при этом не затронуть другие буквы ХА в наименовании товаров.

Из прайса нужные строки я вытягиваю, но как заменить не понимаю.

```html
df.loc[df.Название.str.contains(r'\d+х\d+х\d+', re.IGNORECASE)]
```

в найденном для всех строк наименования товара нужно все вхождения, попавшиее под шаблон [ru]1х2х3 заменить на [en]1x2x3, где 1 2 3 - разнокалиберные цифровые значения.

Помогите пожалуйста примером решения такой задачки. В интернете нахожу примеры замен, но они как правило "как заменить такой знак(   на вот такой)" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [`Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'(\d+)х(\d+)х(\d+)', r'\1x\2x\3', case=False)
```

[**Пример работы регулярного выражения**](https://regex101.com/r/fMzE2F/1)

Выражение найдет и захватит в отдельные подмаски последовательности из 1 и более цифр (с помощью `(\d+)`), а в шаблоне замены подставит эти значения с помощью обратных ссылок.

Благодаря аргументу `case=False` поиск регистронезависим.

Comment: Если люди заполняли, я бы оставил один знак (второй вполне может быть уже на английском :) ) и еще возможные пробелы добавил (\d+)\s*х\s*(\d+)